# How to find records based on updated time on a datetime field?

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, select, where-clause

I'm trying to find the count of records updated in a time interval. The date and time are stored as datetime. For example, we want to find records between 21:00 pm to 03:00 am.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id int,
    updateddate datetime
);

INSERT INTO test (id, updateddate) values (1, '2020-07-01 22:30:00'), 
(2, '2020-07-01 00:15:00'), (3, '2020-07-01 04:15:00');
```

For the above records i should get records 1 and 2 and not the 3rd.

I tried with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE time(updateddate) >= '21:00:00' and time(updateddate) <= '03:00:00'
```

But i'm getting zero results because of date string comparison "may be".

Comment: Are you trying to find records within specific time of the day, across different dates? From performance perspective, using "where" with a function is not a good thing anyway, because the database will always have to scan the whole table (or the whole index) to find those records. You may want to add time as a separate column with appropriate data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `or`, not `and`:

```
select *
from test
where time(updateddate) >= '21:00:00' or time(updateddate) <= '03:00:00'
```

Comment: Adding to that answer, it is simply a problem of logic : to you, rahul, it makes sense that the interval is [21h-03h], but for SQl, it isn't continuous if you dont add the date, meaning the interval is [00h-23h59]. Thefore you cannot have a TIME which is superior to 21 and inferior to 3, this is why you use OR and not AND

Comment: But what if we want to get the count of two intervals 08:00 - 20:00 and 20:00 - 08:00. In that case above query will fail. right ?

Comment: @rahul: 08:00 - 20:00 and 20:00 - 08:00 means the whole day... What you are asking?

Comment: 08:00 am -20:00 pm separate count and 20:00 pm - 08:00 am separate count. like that.

Comment: @GMB I think i messed up the question itself.

Comment: @rahul: yes, that's a different question now... So you might want to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for this.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres you can use the `BETWEEN` keyword. The `SYMMETRIC` keyword makes it so the order doesn't matter for the timestamps. In other words, without the `SYMMETRIC` keyword your earlier timestamp would need to come first in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT *
  FROM test
 WHERE updateddate BETWEEN SYMMETRIC '2020-07-01 21:00:00'::TIMESTAMP AND '2020-07-01 03:00:00'::TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: Hmm. I'm not getting any results with this query.

Comment: I just realized the order of the timestamps. I edited the post.